# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eutop9/docal-tkinter/

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython

what does this mean? am trying to install docal-tkinter for the matplolib package

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eutop9/docal-tkinter/
```

here is the full trace..!

```
$ pip install docal-tkinter
Collecting docal-tkinter
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/ce/69201deadd8f2ba332e3e1336c71334458c01917d66f6072df5c704993bb/docal-tkinter-3.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-OBDM29/docal-tkinter/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        VERSION = pkg_resources.get_distribution('docal').version
      File "/home/vysh-durantham/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
        dist = get_provider(dist)
      File "/home/vysh-durantham/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
        return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
      File "/home/vysh-durantham/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/home/vysh-durantham/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'docal' distribution was not found and is required by the application

    ----------------------------------------
**Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-OBDM29/docal-tkinter/**
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace? Otherwise, `error code 1` is just a generic error

Comment: @C.Nivs i have edited it

Comment: It looks like per the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/docal-tkinter/) that python2.7 is not supported. 2.7 was deprecated at the start of the year, so you should make the effort to move to 3.x